# Open slideshow image on new page

Tags: php, sql, slideshow

First time here and hoping someone can help me. Apologies if I've done anything wrong with regards to posting this question here...

I've created a slide show (using PHP) based on 8 images loaded from an SQL database (PHPMyAdmin)

I want to be able to click on any one image to open a new page which will then show a larger version of the same.

I've scoured the internet and various other forums but struggling to find any help.

Please let me know if you require any further information prior to providing an answer. Any help will be hugely appreciated.

```
<div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext"><?php echo $i . " / 8" ?></div>
    <a href="http://stu10.lccwebtest.co.uk/getimage.php"> 
    <img src="<?php echo $product["Product_Image"];?>" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: Also, the code I've shown here just shows the slideshow images from the database and figured this is what needs altering to allow for the implementation I require. "getimage.php" is the new page I want the larger image to be shown on. Right now, the page is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to end the anchor tag after the image (so the image is part of the link), set it's target attribute to _blank (so it opens in a new page), and finally pass some reference to getimage.php (so it can load the larger image). For example:

```
<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext"><?php echo $i . " / 8" ?></div>
  <a href="http://stu10.lccwebtest.co.uk/getimage.php?id=<?php echo $product["ID"];?>" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="<?php echo $product["Product_Image"];?>" style="width:100%">
  </a>
</div>
```

I've made an assumption on what your primary key is for "products", replace "ID" in my example above with the correct primary key.

---

Based on further discussion we established that getimage.php has no other function other than to show the larger image. So in that case how about doing away with it and adding the larger image url directly to the anchor as in the below:

```
<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext"><?php echo $i . " / 8" ?></div>
  <?php $largerImageUrl = $product["Product_Image"]; //replace the code here with your actual larger image url for this slide ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $largerImageUrl;?>" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="<?php echo $product["Product_Image"];?>" style="width:100%">
  </a>
</div>
```

That reduces a lot of extra work. The only times you'd need a script in the middle would be if the larger image location was a secret or you wanted to somehow record the number of times it was viewed or you wanted to display some other html around the image. In other words, if it had some other function.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you! For example now I see the following in the url - "/getimage.php?id=thelastofus.jpg" when I click on one of my images in the slideshow.

Comment: For that I need to understand your reason for "getimage.php"? It seems you are simply using the image name as the ID, in other words it seems as though you are simply wanting to show the image on the new page instead of load a different/larger one like you asked? Why not simply put the image name in the anchor href?

Comment: Apologies if not more clear before. I was just tinkering with a few other things as well. I can get the following in the url for the getimage.php page - /getimage.php?id=1 (or other id no. between 1-8 depending which slide I click on)

Comment: So at least I'm on my way now to getting what I need from the slideshow to to the getimage.php page. Much better than my previous efforts

Comment: For now, I need to pull the image with the corresponding id no. in the getimage.php page. Hope that makes a little more sense

Comment: So you are saying you must use getimage.php? In that case are you wanting to send back raw image data or html containing an image tag? In getimage.php you can use the id parameter from the url with $_GET['id'], but please read about the function filter_input and why you should use it.

Comment: I happened to change "id" to  "Product_Image" but this gives me a blank image appearing in the getimage page. On inspection, it's down as img scr source unknown.

Comment: Sorry Mark, missed your earlier comment, I'll be sure to do that, thanks for the advice

Comment: Please tell me, will getimage.php have any other function? If not then I will post another answer that could be what you need.

Comment: It literally won't, it's only function will be to show a larger version of the image clicked on from the slideshow. Sorry for the late reply, boiler packed in and ended up spending the night with the in-laws lol

Comment: I've added a different solution to my answer, maybe it will help.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Works perfectly and makes complete sense. Big thanks!